# Ember if helper for component attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js

I want to do the following

```
{{my-field-component cssClass="(if someCondition 'class1' 'class2')"}}
```

The above does not work for some reason.
What is the correct way to do the same ?

P.S: I want to do this for a custom component attribute & not a DOM element ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Correct way is to omit quotes:

```
{{my-field-component cssClass=(if someCondition 'class1' 'class2')}}
```

If you need to add some static string to that attribute, you can use `concat` helper:

```
{{my-field-component 
  cssClass=(concat 
    'static classes ' 
    (if someCondition 'class1' 'class2') 
    ' some other static classes'
  )
}}
```

In component you also have [`classNameBindings`](https://emberjs.com/api/ember/3.3/classes/Component/properties/classNameBindings?anchor=classNameBindings) for class names.

Comment: Perfect...Thank you so much !!